# XML serialization node name with key value

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization, xml-serialization

I would like to serialize my code to XML.

Now I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SerializationClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Value>Test</Value>
</SerializationClass>
```

and my C# code looks like:

```
public class SerializationClass
{
[XmlElement("Value")]
public string City { get; set; }
}
```

But I would like to have XML like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SerializationClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <City value="Test"></City>
</SerializationClass>
```

Comment: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
2) The xml you want is invalid. (see the MyCityName tag)
3) Show some effort, what have you tried?

Comment: So is it posibble to get XML like: <City value="test">/</City> ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with the class structure you have (without hand coding it).  If you're willing to change the structure, this would work:

```
public class SerializationClass
{
    public City City { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach?

```
public class SerializationClass
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public XElement _City
    {
        get { return new XElement("City", new XAttribute("value", City)); }
        set { City = value.FirstAttribute.Value; }
    }
}
```